# Xamarin.Mac obscure SIGSEGV

Tags: c#, macos, cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I'm encountering an obscure segfault with `xamarin.mac`, this is the (unhelpful) stacktrace :

```
  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplication.NSApplicationMain     (int,string[]) <0xffffffff>
  at MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplication.Main (string[]) <0x00097>
  at gitbookpro.mac.MainClass.Main (string[]) <0x00017>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
```

The crash happens after handling an `SelectionDidChange` on an `NSOutlineView` which does a fair amount of processing.

It's hard to pin point what exactly is causing this crash.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

The error was caused by, `C#` objects being **wrongly garbaged collected**.

They were garbage collected because those objects were being returned to `objective-c` code (native code), and since no reference was kept in the `C#` the garbage collector was deleting them.

This was what was happening :

`1. create C# obj
2. return obj to native code
3. ... wait a little bit ...
4. turn native object back into to C# obj (in event handlers etc ...)
5. Access C# obj <= This would fail occasionally since it was being garbage collected during step #3`

What you should do :

`1. create C# obj
1bis. Keep an extra reference to the object somewhere (in an Dictionary for example)
2. return obj to native code
3. ... wait a little bit ...
4. turn native object back into to C# obj (in event handlers etc ...)
4bis. Remove extra reference
5. Access C# obj <= This would fail occasionally since it was being garbage collected during step #3`

And that's it !